# Expandable row does not collapse when the table is filtered using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, filter

The table has an expandable row that shows details of rows. I have used JavaScript to search for and filter particular row content. But while using the search filter, it shows results but unable to expand the details. I have used bootstrap `collapse` class.

A snippet showing the expandable rows can be found [here](https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/cam/979615).

Here is my filter code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }       
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
        />

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="myInput"
                onkeyup="myFunction()"
                placeholder="Search..."
                title="Type in a name"
            />
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="search-btn" type="button">
                    <i class="bi bi-search"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <table class="table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">First</th>
                    <th scope="col">Last</th>
                    <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="myTable">
                <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#person">
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="person" class="collapse">
                    <td>Jacob</td>
                    <td>Thornton</td>
                    <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Larry</td>
                    <td>the Bird</td>
                    <td>@twitter</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Answer Working transition**

```
function showText() {
    elemContainer.style.opacity = 0;
}

function change() {
    elemContainer.style.opacity = 1;
    elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
    setTimeout(showText, 2500);

    counter++;
    if (counter >= text.length) {
        counter = 0;
        // clearInterval(inst); // uncomment this if you want to stop refreshing after one cycle
    }
}
```

Comment: You are hiding all `trs`  that's why it doesn't work . Instead change `table.getElementsByTagName("tr")` to `table.querySelectorAll("tr[data-toggle='collapse']")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @swati suggested, replacing `table.getElementsByTagName("tr")` with `table.querySelectorAll("tr[data-toggle='collapse']")` resolve the problem.

Here is the working code:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.querySelectorAll("tr[data-toggle='collapse']");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if (td) {
            txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
            if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
        />

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                id="myInput"
                onkeyup="myFunction()"
                placeholder="Search..."
                title="Type in a name"
            />
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="search-btn" type="button">
                    <i class="bi bi-search"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <table class="table">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">First</th>
                    <th scope="col">Last</th>
                    <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="myTable">
                <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#person">
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="person" class="collapse">
                    <td>Jacob</td>
                    <td>Thornton</td>
                    <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
                <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#person1">
                    <td>Larry</td>
                    <td>the Bird</td>
                    <td>@twitter</td>
                </tr>
        <tr id="person1" class="collapse">
                    <td>Jacob</td>
                    <td>Thornton</td>
                    <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```